# I can't run JUnit 5.9.x tests in Eclipse 2023-09 (4.29.0)

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, gradle, junit5, buildship

**Hi
I've start with start.spring.io just like below** 
[image]

**and I was trying to check if test is okay or not by default.** 
[image]
[image]

**but it wasn't even start to it. and I got this error in console instead of test results.**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.getTestClassNames(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:50)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.java:46)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.reportEngineFailure(OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:203)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:94)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

**I googled. people said that it was seemed that related with jupiter-api version.
so I added some dependencies like this. but it didn't work.**

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'hello'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.3') /// added version
    testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.3') /// added version
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**I also tried in different way. I added Java Build Path on my Eclipse IDE but it didn't work too.**  
(right click on my project > Properties > Java Build Path 
 > Modulepath(already tried classpath too.) > Add Library > JUnit

**I didn't see same case about JUnit error with `'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'`. 

so I'm confused now. please help.**

Comment: Does it work with `5.10.0` instead of `5.9.3`? By the way, the green highlighting and the _Coverage_ view at the bottom right indicate that you may have run _Profile_ by mistake. You can get right of the green highlighting in the _Coverage_ view via the _Remove All Sessions_ button.

Comment: You cannot override versions of libraries that are declared by spring boot dependency management through explicit version declaration within the `dependencies` block. Instead you have to use the mechanism described in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-override-dependency-versions#2-gradle

Comment: What @johanneslink said. IME, it usually is the additional dependencies of the library you're trying to use that cause issues. Those issues are typically because one of those dependencies used a feature in Java that later Java versions (which you're now using) have removed. You can check which packages have been removed from Java here (assuming you're using Java 17 LTS): https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/migrate/removed-apis.html

Comment: @howlger I tried it with 5.10.0 instead of 5.9.3, it didn't worked :( but thanks for your reply! ;)

Comment: @johannseslink Okay I see. but what I just tried with eclipse project generated by start.spring.io didn't work. so my post what i wrote is what I'd tried to find another way.

Comment: The missing method [`getAncestors`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/TestDescriptor.html#getAncestors()) is part of `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.10.0` of JUnit 5.10.0, which is currently the latest release. In lower versions the method is missing (it is the other way around than @majixin says). So the question is: by what is it used? Please show a [complete, but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including a `build.gradle` and test code.

Comment: Had same issue(without spring) after update Eclipse to 2023-09. But I resolved it by  updating junit version to 5.10.0 in build.gradle. Anyway it really strange had such issue after just regular Eclipse update.

Comment: @userand So you assume that it is the same issue, but can you proof it with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @howlger I've answered below, hope it helps!

Comment: I was able to reproduce it with the example from @userand. Adding the line `testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.9.3'` to the dependencies, right-clicking and choosing _Gradle > Refresh Gradle Project_ fixed it for me.

Comment: @userand Reporting it [here](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues) would help. It's not reproducible with m2e, the Maven support for Eclipse. So I guess in contrast to m2e, Buildship does not choose the right JUnit launcher, but uses the junit-platform-launcher that is included in Eclipse and which has been updated in Eclipse 2023-09 to 1.10.0.

Comment: @howlger OMG! It works! God bless you! I'm not gonna even make it without your helps!

Comment: I have reported it here https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1264

EDIT: It's been reported here too https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1265

Comment: @DanieleRepici And I have reported it here https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1265

Comment: I have closed mine and linked it to yours. Let's use yours :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems an issue of Eclipse Buildship with JUnit less than 5.10.0 and Eclipse 2023-09 (4.29) which I reported here:

[Eclipse Buildship issue #1265: ***NoSuchMethodError when running a JUnit 5.9.3 test in Eclipse 2023-09 (4.29)***](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1265)

**Workarounds**:

- In `build.gradle`, add the dependency `testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.9.3'` or
- Upgrade to JUnit 5.10.0: `testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.10.0'`
- See [Daniele Repici's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150487/6505250) for a workaround without changing `build.gradle`

**Cause**:

It seems Buildship does not choose the corresponding `junit-platform-launcher` (as m2e seems to do; at least this issue cannot be reproduced with Maven), but uses the `junit-platform-launcher` version that is shipped with Eclipse. And in Eclipse 4.29 `junit-platform-launcher` has been upgraded to 1.10.0. But `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.10.0` calls [`org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.html::getAncestors`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.10.0/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/TestDescriptor.html#getAncestors()) which has been introduced in `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.10.0` and which is missing in `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.9.3` in JUnit 5.9.3.

Answer (score 3):

I found a nice **workaround** that doesn't require you to change the project.

This comes **useful when modifying your project's dependencies is not an option** (e.g. if you'd have to justify to the rest of your team using other kinds of IDE why you would override Spring Boot's JUnit and/or if you are working on 50+ different projects).

In Eclipse, go to **Window** --> **Preferences** --> **Gradle**.
In the **Advanced Options** section, under **Program Arguments**, add: `-Pjunit-jupiter.version=5.10.0`.

Click **Apply**.

This has the same effect as adding `ext[junit-jupiter.version]=5.10.0` to your *build.gradle* file, but saves you from modifying your project and will work for all your projects.

This works because of the way Spring Boot Management plugin works. The Spring Boot dependencies BOM uses placeholders for all its versions. [You can find the placeholder names in Maven by clicking on the POM link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.6.3/spring-boot-dependencies-2.6.3.pom).

Comment: Nice! For a specific project this can also be done in _Project > Properties: Gradle_.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is only about Eclipse 2023-09 and Junit compatibility.
@howlger asked minimal example to confirm, so here is it.
I've created new gradle project(wrapper, version 8.1.1) with standard source  layout.

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileJava {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

dependencies {    
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.3")
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.3")
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'JunitBug'
```

StubTest.java

```
package com.junitbug;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

    class StubTest {
        @Test
        void test() {
            boolean b = true;
            assertTrue(b);
        }
    }
```

After test run in Eclipse I have the same exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.getTestClassNames(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:50)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.java:46)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.reportEngineFailure(OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:203)
    ....
```

Updating junit version to **5.10.0** in build.gradle fixed the issue.
Note that "gradlew test" works fine in both case.