# NoSuchMethod on JUnit test after upgrading Eclipse (using Gradle)

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, gradle, junit5

I was using Eclipse 2022-09 and all was working fine.

I manage all dependencies via Gradle. The version of JUnit 5 is defined by the Spring Boot management plugin.

Once I upgraded to Eclipse 2023-09, JUnit tests started failing when executed from within Eclipse.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Set org.junit.platform.engine.TestDescriptor.getAncestors()'
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.getTestClassNames(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:50)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(StackTracePruningEngineExecutionListener.java:39)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.executionFinished(DelegatingEngineExecutionListener.java:46)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.reportEngineFailure(OutcomeDelayingEngineExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:203)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:169)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:93)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:58)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:103)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:94)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DelegatingLauncher.execute(DelegatingLauncher.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

JVM is Adoptium OpenJDK 17 (17.0.8.101-hotspot).

Executing the test via `gradlew test --tests Xyz` is just fine. The problem is when I run the tests in Eclipse (any test).

I've been searching SO for hours and couldn't find a suitable solution or a meaningful explanation.

Comment: Seems the method was dropped in newer versions of JUnit 5, [here (JUnit 5.7.1)](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.1/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/TestDescriptor.html) it isn't listed anymore in contrast to [this (JUnit 5)](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/api/org.junit.platform.engine/org/junit/platform/engine/TestDescriptor.html).

Comment: Does eclipse use any other version of JUnit which might have been updated during the eclipse update?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110882/i-cant-run-junit5-tests-with-eclipseversion-2023-09-4-29-0?noredirect=1#comment135979254_77110882

Comment: Can I force Eclipse to use the platform version that my project declares rather than its own?

Comment: See my answer below.